# Raspberry Pi 1 WiFi adapter receives 2 dhcp addresses

Tags: linux, dhcp, wifi

I have a raspberry pi 1 with a USB WiFi adapter.
The wlan0 interface has 2 IP Addresses and i dont know why:

```
pi@smart-meter:~ $ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:0e:68:e2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 24:05:0f:b1:50:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.155/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 86212sec preferred_lft 75412sec
    inet 192.168.2.158/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary dynamic wlan0
       valid_lft 86214sec preferred_lft 86214sec
```

How can i tell the Raspbian only to use one address?

```
pi@smart-meter:~ $ cat /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.wlan0.leases 
default-duid "\000\001\000\001)\226\277\334\300%\351\030\373I";
lease {
  interface "wlan0";
  fixed-address 192.168.2.158;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 192.168.2.1;
  option dhcp-lease-time 86400;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.2.250;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.2.1;
  option dhcp-renewal-time 43200;
  option ntp-servers 192.168.2.1;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.2.255;
  option dhcp-rebinding-time 75600;
  option domain-name "fritz.box";
  renew 3 2022/05/11 14:08:00;
  rebind 3 2022/05/11 14:08:00;
  expire 3 2022/05/11 14:08:00;
}
lease {
  interface "wlan0";
  fixed-address 192.168.2.158;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 192.168.2.1;
  option dhcp-lease-time 86400;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.2.250;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.2.1;
  option dhcp-renewal-time 43200;
  option ntp-servers 192.168.2.1;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.2.255;
  option dhcp-rebinding-time 75600;
  option domain-name "fritz.box";
  renew 3 2022/05/11 23:36:13;
  rebind 4 2022/05/12 11:09:17;
  expire 4 2022/05/12 14:09:17;
}
```

In the dhcpcd.conf i have nothing changed. `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
pi@smart-meter:~ $ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
#source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid "xxxx"
wpa-psk xxxx
```

*EDIT:*

```
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-05-11 20:04 CEST
Pre-scan script results:
| broadcast-dhcp-discover: 
|   Response 1 of 1: 
|     IP Offered: 192.168.2.105
|     DHCP Message Type: DHCPOFFER
|     Server Identifier: 192.168.2.1
|     IP Address Lease Time: 1d00h00m00s
|     Renewal Time Value: 12h00m00s
|     Rebinding Time Value: 21h00m00s
|     Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
|     Router: 192.168.2.1
|     Domain Name Server: 192.168.2.250
|     Domain Name: fritz.box
|     Broadcast Address: 192.168.2.255
|_    NTP Servers: 192.168.2.1
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 1.41 seconds
```

Comment: `sudo nmap --script broadcast-dhcp-discover 255.255.255.255 -p67` to test if more as one dhcp is running

Comment: @djdomi That would be surprising to me, doesnt seem like it. :/

Comment: well, we still have in here the issue that raspberry is a end user device which is not on topic for serverfault.com but might be on topic on superuser.com. does the double ip makes an issue? why don't you set it statically?